# How To Get HTML Select Option Text And Post To PHP Variable Using Jquery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="MySelect" onchange="run(this)">
        <option value="year 1">year 1</option>
        <option value="year 2">year 2</option>
        <option value="year 3">year 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I am trying to get the selected option text and store this in a php variable. To use later down the page.

The onChange event calls the run() function. In my script.js file.

**Js/Ajax**

```
function run(sel) {

    var i = sel.selectedIndex;
    alert(i);
    alert(sel.options[i].text);
    if (i != -1) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "home.php",
            data: { opValue : sel.options[i].text},
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The data opValue gets stored in the $_POST array. Then below i am trying to print the array, store in variable

**Home.php**

```
<?php
       print_r($_POST);
     if(isset($_POST['opValue']))
     {
       echo 'set';
       print_r($_POST);
       $option = $_POST['opValue'];
       echo $option ;
     }
?>
```

Though it doesn't work, it doesn't reach the echo set. Which suggest the post variable is not being set. What am i doing wrong here, this is fairly new to me and i am still a beginner in php/ajax/js.

P.S i have opted to do it this way as i do not want the page to reload/refresh.

regards.

**EDIT:**

1. Added alert(data)

Now when i select year 2 in the response i am receiving this notable info.

```
Array
(
    [opValue] => year 2
)
1year 2year 2Array
(
    [opValue] => year 2
)
```

Comment: "it doesn't reach the echo set" — How do you know? What are you doing to look at the response?

Comment: not related but you could use `$(sel).val()` to get the selected value

Comment: Are you sure the Ajax function works correctly? try to echo a plain string in the php instead and see if that does anything.

Also it might help to see the console errors if you are using chrome - f12 -> ESC

Comment: Please stop user `alert()` for troubleshooting. Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @Quentin, i set an echo before the isset and one inside of it. It doesn't reach the one inside of it.

Comment: @Pete thats good to know.

Comment: @user1638362 — What are you doing to look at the response?

Comment: @Jackson Ajax function is firing the alert() is running etc.

Comment: Your echos should be returned in the `data` object so `console.log` the `data` to see if it is there rather than just alerting success

Comment: What do your browser's developer tools show? Is the HTTP request formatted as you expect?

Comment: @Quentin can you please expand on what you're asking me, as i said at the bottom this is pretty new to me.

Comment: @user1638362 — None of the code you are sharing will show you what the output of the PHP is, so what are you doing to find out what the output of the PHP is?

Comment: @user1638362, why aren't you doing this, `alert(data)` to see the response from PHP?

Comment: @Quentin i am printing the $_POST global variable: before AND after the isset: print_r($_POST);

Comment: @user1638362, that code is ***server-side.***

Comment: @user1638362 — That will output some data to the HTTP response. What are you doing to get that data out of the HTTP response and into your eyes?

Comment: @Quentin In that case nothing, something you can suggest i could do to check this?

Comment: so alert(data) shows this when i select year 2 :  - > Array
(
    [opValue] => year 2
)
1year 2year 2Array
(
    [opValue] => year 2
)

Comment: okay so your if is being hit and returned, you just need to do something with the data that is returned in your ajax success function

Comment: You can try to call a javascript function, alert(),  from your php: `echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert($_POST["opValue"])</script>';`

Answer (score 1):

You need a function for this.
Just call the function anywhere you want it to show the options.

```
function mySelect(){

    $optArray = array('year 1','year 2','year 3');
    $options = '';
    foreach($optArray as $items){
        $options.="<option value='$items'>" . $items ."</option>";
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Call the function:

```
<select>
  <?= mySelect() ?>
</select>
```

Comment: It is never needed or beneficial to repeat the option's text as its `value` attribute -- just omit the `value` attribute from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the data being echoed out of PHP because you aren't looking at the data you are getting.

Your JavaScript is accepting the HTTP response, and then alerting "Success".

Alert the `data` argument to the success function instead.

Comment: Edit this answer with solution if you have found problem, ty

Comment: The problem was that you weren't looking at the data you were getting back. Now you are. The solution is "Look at `data`".

Comment: Do i need to assign OpValue to Data In the success function?

Comment: @user1638362 — You already are. That is what `echo $option ;` is doing already.

Comment: So i am not seeing it on the page, only in the Http response. So i need to look for something to output the http response $option var to the page? Am i on the right lines? :/

Comment: Yes. If you want to put it on the page, then you need to write JavaScript to put it on the page. http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML

Comment: I don't understand this bit, if its stored in the php variable $option why can not echo this out like any other php variable or use this value of this variable later down the page for something else

Comment: Because your code is telling the browser to make the response available to JavaScript, not to load a new page. i.e. because you are doing Ajax and that's the point of Ajax.

Comment: So clarify for me what do i need to do in order to use the value in $option later down the page for something else. e.g i plan to do if $option is year 1 then display something.

Comment: You take `data` and then do stuff with it using JavaScript. Stackoverflow isn't the place to write a JavaScript tutorial, I linked to one above.

Comment: So this is what i have been asking for help with in my original question "How To Get HTML Select Option Text And Post To PHP Variable Using Jquery/Ajax". Are you telling me that the process to do this is too long that it won't fit in an answer reply?

Comment: Also the above tutorial you linked is more of a general tutorial, and as this is my one and only requirement for ajax it seems a bit excessive to go through, not fully knowing if im going to find what im looking for.

Comment: @user1638362 — It *is* in a PHP variable. The problem is (and you didn't make this clear in the original question) that you seem to want it in a PHP variable in `index.php` (or whatever you are calling the page with the JS in it) instead of `home.php` (which you are requested with Ajax) but `index.php` has already executed and returned an HTML page to the browser before `home.php` is even requested.

Comment: no i want it in home.php i only have 1 php file. home.php.

Comment: It doesn't usually make sense for an Ajax request to be sent to the same URL as usually returns the HTML document that contains the JS that makes the Ajax request. Usually you would have a separate URL providing a lightweight web service. My point stands though - you have two separate HTTP requests and the second one will not travel back in time to change the response to the first one.

Comment: I have altered it to make it clear for you that i wanted it in home.php as this is where my .php code is running from.

Comment: so from what i can gather you are telling me i am going about fulfilling my requirement the wrong way. the requirement being i need  the selected option value to be stored in a php var on the same page, without having to refresh/reload the page. Is there other methods to do this?

Comment: What you have so far is fine, you just need to update the page with the new data using JavaScript instead of expecting magic to happen with PHP that finished running minutes previously.

Comment: You're confusing me now. Previously saying " doesn't usually make sense for an Ajax request to be sent to the same URL" to now "what you have so far is fine". What i can tell from this is that the way i am getting the option value is not the normal way someone would get it if they diditn want to refresh the page, but then it is :/. i'd like to keep this specific the what i am trying to achieve if there is a better way i am willing to try it:/.

Comment: What you have now *with the JavaScript* is fine (as a starting point). You'll want to refactor the server side into two parts. One to load the initial page, and one to respond to the Ajax request (with just the data you need to determine what to change, using JS, on the page)